# How to bring a spring-boot application with spring-boot-docker-compose to production

Tags: spring-boot, docker-compose, spring-boot-docker-plugin

I am developing a spring-boot 3.2.1 application using spring-boot-docker-compose support, which is really cool for the development stage. Its just a utility application that needs to mock some complex web service communication. So my goal is to get it into "production" in such a way that a user of this application just needs to check out the source and then use docker-compose to create the entire application environment, including building and running the application. I want to keep the requirements as low as possible and let the code do all the configuration itself.

And I am thinking im missing something here...

So far, so good. My idea was to do this with two compose files. One for development (compose.yaml) and one for production (compose-full.yml) when someone just wants to use the latest version.

so here are my compose.yaml file:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: ./.env
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: ${MONGODB_USER}
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MONGODB_PASSWORD}
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: kmc
    ports:
      - ${MONGODB_LOCAL_PORT}:${MONGODB_DOCKER_PORT}

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - ${MONGODB_EXPRESS_LOCAL_PORT}:${MONGODB_EXPRESS_DOCKER_PORT}
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: ${MONGODB_USER}
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: ${MONGODB_PASSWORD}
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL: mongodb://${MONGODB_USER}:${MONGODB_PASSWORD}@mongo:${MONGODB_LOCAL_PORT}/
```

This works fine during development because of the docker-compose support with spring-boot-docker-compose.

Now here's my full-compose.yaml and Dockerfile to get the point of what I'm trying to achieve.

full-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: ./.env
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: ${MONGODB_USER}
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MONGODB_PASSWORD}
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: kmc
    ports:
      - ${MONGODB_LOCAL_PORT}:${MONGODB_DOCKER_PORT}

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - ${MONGODB_EXPRESS_LOCAL_PORT}:${MONGODB_EXPRESS_DOCKER_PORT}
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: ${MONGODB_USER}
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: ${MONGODB_PASSWORD}
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL: mongodb://${MONGODB_USER}:${MONGODB_PASSWORD}@mongo:${MONGODB_LOCAL_PORT}/

  app:
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    build: ./
    restart: on-failure
    env_file: ./.env
    ports:
      - ${SPRING_LOCAL_PORT}:${SPRING_DOCKER_PORT}
    environment:
      SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON: '{
          "spring.data.mongodb.uri" : "mongodb://$MONGODB_USER:$MONGODB_PASSWORD@mongo:$MONGODB_DOCKER_PORT/",
          "spring.data.mongodb.database" : "kcm"
        }'
    volumes:
      - .m2:/root/.m2
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

Dockefile:

```
FROM maven:3.8.5-openjdk-17
LABEL authors="hizr"

WORKDIR /callback-mock
COPY . .
COPY .mvn/settings.xml /usr/share/maven/conf/
RUN mvn clean install

CMD mvn spring-boot:run
```

So my problem is that in this configuration spring-boot will try to start docker from within a docker container, which makes no sense.

I could create different maven profiles to separate the spring-boot-docker-compose dependency, but I do not think this is an elegant solution.

Am I missing something? How can I containerise the whole application environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work with two profiles. Are there other solutions?

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-docker-compose</artifactId>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                    <optional>true</optional>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-testcontainers</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mongodb</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties>
                <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
            </properties>
        </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: I accepted it as a good solution. It is clean, it is declarative, it is easy to understand. Looks solid to me.